# Postgres slow to access tables from GUI

Tags: performance, postgresql, user-interface, settings

Postgres is installed locally.

Weird one this, but when I start up Postgres' GUI (version 1.81 Dec 3 2013) and access anything for the first time (drill down and select a datbasebase to work with, or open SQL editor window, or drill down and view the data on a selected table) it's very slow to respond (about 20 seconds) - almost as if it's trying to access something but can't and this slow response never changes.

However, once open, SQL queries etc run fine.

The config files are all at default settings. I've tried disabling the w8 firewall, switching off Zone Alarm.  Some settings then from pg_hba file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:
# local   all             all                                     trust # doesn't work
# local all all 127.0.0.1/32    md5 # doesn't work
#host   all all 127.0.0.1/32    trust
#host   all all 0.0.0.0/0   trust
#host   all all 192.168.1.101/0 md5
#host   all all 127.0.0.1/32    255.255.255.0   md5 # doesn't work
host    all all 127.0.0.1/32    md5 # Works


# IPv6 local connections:
#host    all     all     192.68.1.0/24   md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
#host    all     all     ::1/32  md5
```

If I access another db across the network, it's fine (fast, no problems) so I'm thinking it's a setting that needs to be changed, but I'm puzzled as to which one.

Comment: When accessing a table, it says "Retrieving details on table xyz... Done" quite quickly but then there's a long pause...

Comment: All sorted.   At first I thought it was the GUI at fault and so I downloaded trial versions.  But the problem was still there (ie slow opening SQL windows, initially accessing tables etc...), but come 2015 and trying to do something else caused me to uninstall ZONEALARM, and that did the trick!  Ok, I had to also add ::1/32 md5 blah (as advised when trying to connect to the db by postgres) but now everything's fast and working a treat.